# Limits of inverse tangent

Tags: limits, trigonometry

[Inverse tan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1fWi.png)

> I have some confusion on the role $\tan^{-1}$. I know that the limit of $1/x$ is undefined. I am on that path that tells me to make tan to arctan? any more guidelines?

Comment: The limit is not undefined.  It is simply the case of as $x$ tends to $0$, $\frac{1}{x}$ tends to infinity

Answer (score 1):

$\tan^{-1}(x)=\arctan(x)$. The end behaviours of $\arctan(x)$ are towards $\frac{\pi}{2}$ from underneath as $x\to\infty$, and towards $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ from above as $x\to -\infty$. Hence,

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\arctan\left(\frac1x\right)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\arctan(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\arctan\left(\frac1x\right)=\lim_{x\to -\infty}\arctan(x)=-\frac{\pi}{2}$$